# Running a python flask app on Heroku fails

Tags: python, heroku

I have a python web app that I can successfully run on my local machine with this command

```
python run.py
```

I have successfully deployed the code to Heroku, but when I go to my application URL I get this  error message that says

```
Application error. An error occurred in the application and your page could not be served. If you are the application owner, check your logs for details. You can do this from the Heroku CLI with the command
heroku logs --tail
```

Looking at the log tails yields

```
 heroku logs --tail                            ✘ 2
```

›   Error: Missing required flag:
›     -a, --app APP  app to run command against

My Procfile contains

```
web: python --app monte-carlo-retirement run.py
```

where monte-carlo-retirement is the name of my app

Comment: are all your imports in requirement txt?

Comment: Yes. My requirement.txt looks like this:
SQLAlchemy==1.3.19
alembic==1.4.3
Flask==1.1.2
WTForms==2.3.3
Pillow==7.2.0
numpy==1.19.2
pandas==1.1.2
python-dateutil==2.8.1
DateTime==4.3
itsdangerous==1.1.0
matplotlib==3.3.1

Comment: The error message seems to imply I have a problem with my Procfile, This is my first attempt to use Heroku

Answer (score 1):

You're conflating two things.

The error about a missing `-a` or `--app` argument is related to [running the `heroku` CLI *locally*](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-cli-commands). Instead of just `heroku logs --tail`, try `heroku logs --app=monte-carlo-retirement --tail`. This should give you useful log output.

See also [How does `heroku config` know what app to use?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50198860/354577) and [How to avoid the --app option with heroku CLI?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55470675/354577).

Your *`Procfile`* doesn't need that argument. You deploy your code to a particular app, so there is no confusion about what app it applies to. Furthermore, you are giving that argument to `python` where it is meaningless.

Take it out of your `Procfile`:

```
web: python run.py
```

Then commit and redeploy.

Now, you haven't shown us what is in your `run.py`, but this would be a weird way to run it in production. A more common approach would be to use something like [Gunicorn](https://gunicorn.org/).

Install it locally and add it to your `requirements.txt` (if you are using `pip`) or `Pipfile` / `Pipfile.lock` (if you are using Pipenv). Then modify your `Procfile` again to something like

```
web: gunicorn run:app
```

where `app` is the name of the Flask object in `run.py`.

Comment: Thank you Chris. I am a relative newbie to web development. Your answer got me "unstuck".